# How do I replace part of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Supposed I have the following string:

```
string str = "<tag>text</tag>";
```

And I would like to change 'tag' to 'newTag' so the result would be:

```
"<newTag>text</newTag>"
```

What is the best way to do it?

I tried to search for <[/]*tag> but then I don't know how to keep the optional [/] in my result...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why use regex when you can do:

```
string newstr = str.Replace("tag", "newtag");
```

or

```
string newstr = str.Replace("<tag>","<newtag>").Replace("</tag>","</newtag>");
```

Edited to @RaYell's comment

Comment: or if you fear that `tag` can be also the part of the text you can do `str.Replace("<tag>", "<newTag>").Replace("</tag>", "</newTag>");`

Comment: Because this works for the given example but not so well in practice where you could have <SomeOtherElement> here is the word tag </SomeOtherElement>.  There is a side-effect of just doing the string.Replace call.

Comment: you could do `str.Replace("tag>", "newTag>");` which is one pass and solves the problem of "tag" being elsewhere in the string.

Answer (score 3):

To make it optional, simply add a "?" AFTER THE "/", LIKE THIS:

```
<[/?]*tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "<tag>text</tag>";
string newValue = new XElement("newTag", XElement.Parse(str).Value).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your most basic regex could read something like:

```
// find '<', find an optional '/', take all chars until the next '>' and call it
//   tagname, then take '>'.
<(/?)(?<tagname>[^>]*)>
```

If you need to match every tag.

---

Or use positive lookahead like:

```
<(/?)(?=(tag|othertag))(?<tagname>[^>]*)>
```

if you only want `tag` and `othertag` tags.

---

Then iterate through all the matches:

```
string str = "<tag>hoi</tag><tag>second</tag><sometag>otherone</sometag>";

Regex matchTag = new Regex("<(/?)(?<tagname>[^>]*)>");
foreach (Match m in matchTag.Matches(str))
{
    string tagname = m.Groups["tagname"].Value;
    str = str.Replace(m.Value, m.Value.Replace(tagname, "new" + tagname));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var input = "<tag>text</tag>";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "(</?).*?(>)", "$1newtag$2");
```

Comment: Warning! This will replace ANY tag, not just "tag". If you have `<tag>text</tag><other>text2</other>`, you end up with `<newtag>text</newtag><newtag>text2</newtag>`.